# How to import android project as library and NOT compile it as apk (Android studio 1.0)

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I tried to import a project(projLib) as dependency for another project(projAPK).

projAPK gradle has this :

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libs:NewsAPI')
    compile project(':projLib')
}
```

but when i sync the gradle it gives this error:

> Error:Dependency Android_2015:projLib:unspecified on project projAPK resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: /Users/myname/Documents/Development/Android_2015/libs/projAPK/build/outputs/apk/projLib-release-unsigned.apk

so I guess there are two solution to this:

1. somehow make gradle think that projLib is a library that shouldn't be compiled to apk
2. somehow make gradle NOT compile the projLib explicitly

The problem is, I couldn't find how to do any of that.
Would be awesome if you guys can help :)

Answer (score 329, accepted):

In **projLib**'s build.gradle file, you'll see a statement like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

which tells Gradle to build it as an application, generating an APK.  If you change it to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

it will build as a library, generating an AAR, and it should work.

If you also need **projLib** to generate a separate APK, then you'll have to do some refactoring to pull the common code that you need out into a third library module, and have both APKs depend on it.

Libraries aren't allowed to set an `applicationId`, so if you see an error message to that effect, remove it from the library's build script.

Comment: Thank you sir, this worked. Is there any reading/documentation you can recommend me about these plugin things?

Comment: I tried that and got a new error: `Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.bulletnoid.android.widget.StaggeredGridViewDemo' in default config.` The StaggeredGridViewDemo is a package in the library I tried to import as a module.

Comment: I just removed the application Id line from defaultConfig{} and it worked.

Comment: also you will need to add 'tools:replace="android:icon" on the <application ... >... to override the main icon

Answer (score 24):

**In  module gradle file**-

**Replace**  `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` with `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Then **remove** `applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxxx"`

**Clean and Build**

Comment: all is doing in module gradle file

Answer (score 1):

just add these lines to library `gradle` file and remove other sections

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
  ,...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts), use this notation:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    // ...
}
```