# Android Studio make my test module depend of application module

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I want to make in Android Studio my test module to be dependent of application module, but can not achieve this, have mistake

```
Error:Dependency AndroidApp:app:unspecified on project TestsRobotium resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: D:\android\MEWE\AndroidApp\app\build\apk\MeWe.apk
```

In my test.gradle I added provided project(':app') in dependency tag (it is done by Android studio automatically)

How would I resolve this? I need dependency on src, res folders of my main app and need to know R file

Comment: Take a look [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536491/how-to-import-android-project-as-library-and-not-compile-it-as-apk-android-stud?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364565/how-to-import-material-design-library-to-android-studio?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Feels like good decithion in a link provided.
But I need application to be a project(module), not library, and need to have dependency on it (so I can rely on src, res and r.java of application from tests). Maybe there is some way achieving this?

Comment: @AntonKizema were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @amadib nope, I simply moved test code into app module.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible using `com.android.test` plugin. Works fine for Java and resources stuff.

An example by Google can be found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/module-flavor1-androidTest-only/build.gradle).

Basically you create a separate module for testing and define which module and flavor should be tested. I've just checked it and it has some issues with working with the IDE, but runs fine with gradle command line.